# What resources are needed to start SMS programming through Java?

Tags: java, sms

1. What APIs are required? Where can I find them?
2. Where could I find a good tutorial to start with?
3. And good book?

Please help! Thanks so much in advance!!

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you want to do? Are you planning to have a mobile connected to your computer or do you just want to send and receive sms messages using an API and a service provider such as http://aql.com

Comment: I want to send messages using an API. I have a connection (username, password etc.) to my operator. I need Java APIs to connect the operator and send my messages to mobiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three options:

1. Hook up a mobile phone to your computer and send and receive SMS's.
2. Use an external service, pay them a fee and use the internet in order to let them send the SMS messager for you.
3. Do both 1 and 2

If you choose 1 you will do well with [smslib.org](http://smslib.org/). This is a very stable free application that does all you need. You will find sample code that can get you started fast. You will need a GSM phone or a GSM modem connected via serial port interfaces or IP interfaces. USB or blue-tooth work as serial connections. JavaComm or RxTx will allow you to communicate. [More...](http://smslib.org/doc/about/)

If you choose 2 search the Internet in order to find the appropriate SMS gateway offer that suits your needs (volumes, prices etc.) better. In this case you need follow the instructions they provide. It is usually the easiest approach.

You could also choose 3 in order to have a full back position.

Comment: Many thanks for your help! I want to send SMS through my web site. I am looking for Java APIs to program a web application that could send SMS to the mobile numbers provided to it through a form.

Comment: All three options will work if you run them on a web-server. SMSLib is the API you want. You can do the rest with Struts2 easily.