# sms through usb port using java

Tags: java, applet, sms, usb, communication

I have connected my nokia through data cable to USB port. I need a program in java to access the gsm module of my mobile and send text messages.

which API i need to use for it? communication need to be taken place through USB port.

Thanks & Regards,

Sri

Answer (score 1):

You can use [smslib](http://smslib.org/). It is a very reliable solution. It supports GSM phones and GSM modems connected via serial port interfaces or IP interfaces.

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977301/what-resources-are-needed-to-start-sms-programming-through-java/4977400#4977400) for more.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Kannel](http://www.kannel.org/). It is not a Java application, BTW.

- [Java API for Kannel](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kanneljavaapi/)
- [An Example](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/05/java-api-for-kannel-smswap-gateway-v_24.html)
- [Sending SMS with SMPP, Kannel and Java](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/05/java-api-for-kannel-smswap-gateway-v_24.html)

Comment: Error loading SolarisSerial: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no SolarisSerialParallel in java.library.path
Caught java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.comm.SolarisDriver.readRegistrySerial(Ljava/util/Vector;Ljava/lang/String;)I while loading driver com.sun.comm.SolarisDriver
Error loading SolarisSerial: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no SolarisSerialParallel in java.library.path
Caught java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.comm.SolarisDriver.readRegistrySerial(Ljava/util/Vector;Ljava/lang/String;)I while loading driver com.sun.comm.SolarisDriver
Can't init this card

Answer (score -1):

The phone needs to be hooked up via a serial port for RS-232. Using either a USB data cable or a USB-to-RS232 adapter and a serial data cable.

Use [Java Communications API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html) to connect to the Phone.

Then use the AT command to send and receive SMS messages. There is and example [here](http://www.control.com.sg/at_commands_sms.aspx). It is not specific to Nokia, but it is pretty much a standard command set.